# How to connect PostgreSQL from Mac to Windows MS Server (Python)

Tags: postgresql

I want to connect from my Mac which has **PostgreSQL** installed to my **VMware** which has Microsoft MS Server.

I want to do this through **python**.
My intention is to transfer data from one server to another.

Comment: What do you want to connect in your Mac and Windows? Those 2 are operating systems. What are the programs you want to connect and in which direction?

Comment: I would like to connect my PostgresSQL on Mac to Windows MS Server.

Comment: Postgresql usually doesn't connect to anything, that's why what you're asking doesn't make much sense. Please elaborate more.